# Google Calendar API > no notification sent to non-google user account when adding ACL

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am using google calendar APIs (through the official php client) to manage calendars.
I have a calendar I want to share with a non-google user, with email (let's say) user1@yahoo.com.
So, I have read that I have to add an ACL:

```
$rule = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRule();
$scope = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRuleScope();
$calendarId = "xyz";

$scope->setType("user");
$scope->setValue("user1@yahoo.com");
$rule->setScope($scope);
$rule->setRole("reader");

$createdRule = $calendar_service->acl->insert($calendarId, $rule);
```

When I add this ACL for a google user, a notification is sent to the user (X has shared calendar with you...). When I add the ACL for a NON-google user, NO notification is sent to the email (I am expecting something that invites the user to sign up in google, to let him use google calendar).

I would like:

1) That the action of adding an ACL results in an email sent to the user added even if he is a non-google user

2) OR, to have a way to generate the subscription link (EG I have received this when doing the action manually: https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=xxxxx&invEmailKeyyyyy:zzzzzz

Thanks,

Comment: Seems like a bug, try filing an issue in the [tracker here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: Here's the [issue link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111408324)